# When should IIS redirect to a 404?

Tags: asp.net, iis, http-status-code-404

I have configured IIS to redirect to a custom 404 page when a requested page is not found. However it is also redirecting to the 404 page if a resource such as a css, JavaScript or image file is not found. Is this what should happen?

Although a JS or CSS file should never be missing, it's possible a referenced image doesnt exist on the server as the site is managed using a CMS.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you get redirect on application if a dependent resource is not found?

Comment: What version of IIS are you using? How is the redirect setup?

Comment: IIS6. Website > Properties > Custom Errors tab > 404 > File: PageNotFound.aspx

Answer (score 2):

> it is also redirecting to the 404 page if a resource such as a css, JavaScript or image file is not found. Is this what should happen?

Yes, it is.

If you are trying to access a resource (HTML, JS, images etc) that do not exist, a 404 is correct.

What **shouldn't** happen is a redirect of a page referencing such missing resources.

Comment: "What shouldn't happen is a redirect of a page referencing such missing resources." - That appears to be the default behavior when setting a 404 custom error which is what I was quite surprised with.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior matches the definition

> HTTP standard response code indicating that the client was able to communicate with the server, but the server could not find what was requested